# request from API return as html insted of json

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am working on pulling json file from an API which require login first.

```
import requests
import json

Login_param= {'username':'admin_login','password':'1234','rememberMe':True}
request= requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8686/admin/login',params=Login_param)
print(request)
print(request.headers)


device_array_param={'pageNum':1,'pageSize':1}    
respond2= requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8686/device/Array',params=device_array_param)
print(respond2)
print(respond2.headers)
```

Output:

```
  <Response [200]>
{'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=567ac547-1468-40e0-b524-483747eff319; Path=/; HttpOnly, rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 23-Feb-2021 11:51:07 GMT, rememberMe=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; Path=/; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Thu, 25-Feb-2021 11:51:07 GMT; HttpOnly', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Wed, 24 Feb 2021 11:51:07 GMT'}
<Response [200]>
{'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Language': 'und', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Wed, 24 Feb 2021 11:51:07 GMT'}
```

The `respond2` has `'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'` instead of json file as mentioned in the API return example in the documentary below

[image]

[image]

did I do something wrong?

Comment: Try to use `json=` instead of `params=`.

Comment: You can try sending the request with additional `headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}` argument.

Comment: thank you for the comments but both suggestions do not work.  The `respond2`  always respond `code:200` and the `respond2.headers` always result in the same as my answer above.